# What's the relationship between Mr. X, the Drummers and CryptNet?

Tags: diamond-age

Dr. X sends Hackworth to the Drummer colony in Seattle to work on the Seed. What's the relationship between Dr. X, the Drummers and CryptNet? Are the Drummers a free-for-all community Dr. X hijacks through Hackworth, or willing collaborators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text implies that the Drummers are a free-for-all community which are leveraged first by CryptNet and then, more effectively, by the Celestial Kingdom:

> CryptNet was tied in with something much deeper and more interesting -
> the society of the Drummers.  With their flaky and shallow Western
> perspective, CryptNet didn't grasp the full power of the Drummers'
> collective mind.  But [Dr. X] got it right away.

While Hackworth was able to leverage the Drummers quite well, it is clear that when he was removed as the catalyst, the drummers are not able to continue as willing collaborators.  The "you" in this quote refers to Hackworth, the "we" to the Celestial Kingdom:

> The Seed is almost finished.  When you left, the building of
> it slowed down very much - more than we expected.  We thought that the
> Drummers, after ten years, had absorbed your knowledge and
> could continue the work without you.  But there is something
> in your mind that you have gained through your years of scholarly
> studies that **the Drummers, if they ever had it, have given up and
> cannot get back unless they come out of the darkness and live their
> lives in the light again.**

In other words, they are too submerged in their shared gestalt to be willing collaborators.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember that part.